# What did I do wrong in calculating variance of $f_X(x)=\frac32 x^2+\frac12$?

Tags: statistics

This is a problem that occurred while solving this question: [image]

I found that marginal pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\frac32x^2+\frac12$. At first, I used this formula to calculate the variance in a simple way: $\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-\mathbb E(X)^2$.

I know that $\mathbb E(X)=\int_0^1 xf_Xdx=\frac78,  \mathbb E(X^2)=\int_0^1 x^2f_Xdx=\frac7{15}$. As a result of calculating using this, $\text{Var}(X)=-\frac{287}{960}$ came out. Negative value of variance means that something serious has happened.

As a result of calculating as what variance defined, I got an answer that seems right:
$$
\text{Var}(X)=\int_0^1(x-\mathbb E(X))^2f_Xdx=\frac{133}{960}
$$

So, what kind of mistake did I make that the two calculation results are so different?

Comment: Using your expression I get $E[X]=\frac 58$, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%283x%5E2%2F2%2B1%2F2%29+from+0+to+1).

Comment: God hell, that was just calculation mistake... thanks @lulu !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the item (a), [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) allows us to proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X + Y) & = \frac{3}{2}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}(x + y)(x^{2} + y^{2})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(x^{3} + xy^{2} + x^{2}y + y^{3})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \frac{3}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{y^{2}}{2} + \frac{y}{3} + y^{3}\right)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \frac{3}{2}\times\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4}\right) = \frac{5}{2}
\end{align*}

You can proceed similarly to the function $g(x,y) = xy$. Can you take it from here?

As to the question (b), you are on the right track. Let us determine the marginal density function $f_{X}$:
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(x^{2} + y^{2})\mathrm{d}y = \frac{3}{2}\times\left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{3x^{2}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Therefore one gets that:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X) = \int_{0}^{1}xf_{X}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{3x^{3}}{2} + \frac{x}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{8}
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X^{2}) = \int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f_{X}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{3x^{4}}{2} + \frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{3}{10} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{15}
\end{align*}

Based on such results, you arrive at the desired value for $\text{Var}(X)$.

Analogous reasoning applies to $\text{Var}(Y)$ and $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$.

Once you have at hand all the corresponding results, you can apply  the identity:
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(X + Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) + 2\text{Cov}(X,Y)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!